# What is the difference between "postuli" and "demandi"?

Tags: translation, word-difference

The verb *to ask* can be translated as *postuli* and *demandi*. 
Are the two words equivalent or are there differences?

Comment: Just to add to your confusion, there's also "peti".

Comment: The English `demand` (=postuli) and Esperanto `demandi` (=to ask) are so called _false friends_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Demandi* is the action of requesting information, that is to ask a question.
*Postuli* is making a demand, asking for something.

*Panjo demandis min ĉu mi faris miajn hejmtaskojn.*
"Mom asked me if I did my homework."

*Panjo postulas ke mi ĉiam faru miajn hejmtaskojn.*
"Mom demands(asks of me) that I always do my homework."

Comment: I think “asks that I do my homework” is less severe than “demands that I do my homework”. The former would probably be better translated by _petas ke mi faru mian hejmtaskon_.

Comment: "made" my homework? I've never seen it written that way in English (or at least American English).  We always use do/did. Why made/make?

Comment: So demandi = inquire, postuli = request?

Comment: Thank you Seth, corrected. Non-native EN speaker here.  @ Accumulation: yes that's the gist of it. (Could be requirement instead of request)

Answer (score 6):

*postuli* = to demand; *demandi* = to ask.